# Is there a feature in Emacs for function call hierarchy

Tags: emacs

I am maintaining someone else's code. The code is written in C using GCC 4.4.3 on Linux platform. However, the code jumps around a lot and its difficult to find out where all the functions are called from.

In Visual Studio, there is a feature called 'Call Hierarchy' which will display where functions are called from and called to. Does Emacs (23.1.1) have any such feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic Emacs way to jump to calls is to use `TAGS` file and use the <kbd>M-.</kbd> command. I recommend using [Exuberant C Tags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) with the following command in the root directory of your project :

```
ctags -e --c-kinds=+pxd -R .
```

Then using `visit-tags-table` you can open the TAGS file. With <kbd>M-.</kbd> you can jump to each definition or call to your keyword. Use <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-.</kbd> to jump to another occurrence. Use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd>... to repeat the search.

If you have many projects, you can create a TAGS file for each one of them and then call visit-tags-file to add the TAGS file to your list of TAGS files to search from.

Another classic way (the un*x way), is to use the command <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-grep` to search for occurrences of your keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried that on a small sample project. Worked well. However, I am not sure of your command to create the tags file. ctags -e --c-kinds=pxd -R. I can understand the -e - tags for emacs. --c - c language. -R Recursive so go through all the files and directories in creating the tags file. However, what is -kinds=pxd? Not sure about that. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jermoe. Just wondering how you do you update the TAGS files. I have just added some new functions. However, I cannot navigate to them as it saids "No tags containing ...". I find I have to delete my TAGS file and then generate a new one. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: do a ctags --list-kinds=c to know which kinds of C element you can add or remove from TAGS file using --c-kinds.

Answer (score 5):

http://cedet.sourceforge.net/symref.shtml