# Call hierarchy of methods for Ruby in Emacs?

Tags: ruby, emacs

Like Java in Eclipse, is it possible, in Emacs for Ruby, to see a call hierarchy for a method i.e. to see all the methods that call a method, without doing a grep search?

Comment: Do you mean at run time? Because ruby is a dynamic language there is no way to know exactly where the method is called. But in runtime it's possible to know who was the caller

Comment: No, not at run time. I know it's difficult but was just wondering if tags could do it.

Comment: tags is only useful to see definitions. There might be plugins to jump to a tag (method/class name etc..) definition, but I doubt there is any to do the opposite.

Comment: I found this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649000/is-there-a-feature-in-emacs-for-function-call-hierarchy?rq=1

Comment: Well, you can try that (http://zmalltalker.com/emacs/tags.html). I would actually like to know if that does what you want.